# How to tell when calculating an Intercept Point between two moving objects, when it will never intercept?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, intersection

I'm not a maths person and the formulas you see on maths type questions/answer with all the symbols is completely beyond me - I'm sorry. However I had help about 18 months ago to turn a provided formula into lua script to make the calculation for two aircraft to intercept each other. I will admit, I don't know why that formula works, and I wouldn't know how to change it to make it do other things; I need to get this working for a flight sim project, but learning all the maths for this one problem would take too long and I have no-one who could teach me. (I don't learn well from books). Please be understanding and not too critical of my lack of maths skills.

The premise is one aircraft will maintain it's course (target) and the other (interceptor) will alter it's course to intercept with the target aircraft at some point in the future.

The formula/code I made for that is this (It was based on a simulation page tutorial on calculating lead shots for firing a bullet in an FPS and where it will hit a moving target - obviously that works in an FPS as you intend to only shoot when pointing at a target, but here there is a non-negligible chance of the player asking for an intercept that could never happen):

```
    -- Point intercept(Point const &shooter, double bullet_speed, Point const &target, Vector const &target_velocity)
    -- {
    --     double a = bullet_speed*bullet_speed - target_velocity.dot(target_velocity);
    --     double b = -2*target_velocity.dot(target-shooter);
    --     double c = -(target-shooter).dot(target-shooter);

    --     return target+largest_root_of_quadratic_equation(a,b,c)*target_velocity;
    -- }

  local targetMINUSInterceptor   = TVF.VecSubtract(interceptorVec3Point, targetVec3Point)
  local targetVelocityDotProduct = TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetVelocityAsVec3)

  local a = interceptorSpeedAsNumber * interceptorSpeedAsNumber - targetVelocityDotProduct
  local b = -2 * TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetMINUSInterceptor)
  local c = -TVF.VecDot(targetMINUSInterceptor, targetMINUSInterceptor)

  local result = TVF.VecAdd(targetVec3Point, (TVF.MultiplyVectorByNumber(targetVelocityAsVec3, TVF.GetLargestRootOfQuadraticEquation(a,b,c))))
```

Now, that all works perfectly, but only IF both aircraft are travelling in directions and speeds that CAN intercept (even with required turns for the Interceptor).

However, if you have, for example, the target aircraft heading West, and East of that target you have the Interceptor aircraft heading East (i.e. moving away from each other and already are tail to tail to each other), and allowing for the fact that the interceptor can't go fast enough to catch up and overtake the target aircraft, then the above calculation/formula still gives a position vector, however it's either 'off the map' or in some weird direction and massive magnitude that makes no practical sense.

I need to know when this calculation (or a modified version of it) gives a DEFINITE interception point, and also when it CANNOT give an interception point.

This will allow me to make a branching decision in my code to warn the players when an interception is not possible and the target aircraft would have to change it's direction and/or speed and try again.

Could someone please help? My maths level is very basic trig, so I'd really appreciate it if you could spell it out for me or give me the corrected formula with explanations words for all the terms please.

**EDIT: In response to the great answer below, I wanted to add this.**

This is the quadratic equation I'm using to calculate the intercept point.

```
function TVF.GetLargestRootOfQuadraticEquation(A, B, C) -- A, B, C are all doubles (floats)

  return (B + math.sqrt(B * B - 4 * A * C)) / ( 2 * A)

end
```

I notice that the only difference I can see between my quadratic and the answer below is that mine starts with a positive b and the answer below starts with a negative b.

The thing that confuses me about this, is that if it's possible for the two aircraft to intercept, my maths/code calculates it correctly.

It just gives a weird answer when they definitely can't.

This is confusing. After testing, if I change B to -B at the start, then the 'intercept point' doesn't work anymore and the point it thinks it's going to is way 'off the map' - just like when using that same equation on an interceptor that can't intercept.

So is it just that if the result is < 0 then it can't intercept and if it's > 0 it can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of the behaviour it sounds like your quadratic equation solver is breaking down.
$$\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
For example, if a is 0 (which will happen if the interceptor speed is the same as the target speed) then applying the quadratic formula will result in a divide by zero.

Or, if a is positive (which will happen if the interceptor speed is smaller than the target speed) then the term \$b^2 - 4ac\$ might also be negative. And if that happens, then the result of the square root will be an imaginary number.

I have a solution that doesn't use the quadratic formula. Instead it uses basic trig to give you the angle you need to pursue. I have explained it here:
https://github.com/LSBUSGP/AimAhead

If you can get an intercept direction vector \$Iv\$ (it's possible that you can't if you are going slower than the target) you can dot it with the target motion vector \$Tv\$ to see if travelling at your speed \$Is\$ you will catch the target.

If \$Tv \cdot Iv < Is\$ you will intercept. Note you need to be careful with the lengths of these vectors. I am assuming the length of \$Tv\$ to be the speed of the target, whereas the length of \$Iv\$ is 1. Alternatively, if they are both movement vectors with lengths corresponding to their speeds then you can compare against the square of the speed of the interceptor: \$Tv \cdot Iv < Is^2\$.

Comment: I've updated the question with an edit about the quadratic equation. Is this what's wrong? And if so, why does it still give a good intercept (when interception is possible?).

Comment: The quadratic formula starts with -b as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula

The reason it works for you is that the b value you pass in is already negative. In your code, b should be = 2 * ...

Comment: You can't return a single value for the quadratic formula, you need to return two results and handle some of the special cases. For example, if a is 0, your code will return either an exception of some kind or infinity. If \$b^2 - 4ac\$ is negative, your code will again either return an error, or a complex number. If you do get real answers, the one you want is usually the lowest positive result.